# Scrolling website with angular: states/routing setup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I can't seem to wrap my head around a routing setup for a project I'm working on at the moment. I tried ngRoute, angular-sement-router, now trying ui-router, however I'm still struggling to understand how to use them in my scenario.
I've attached an image to illustrate the kind of a thing I want to achieve. Basically, I need to have two types of pages — one type is a multi-section scrolling page. Another one is just a plain page with text and images.
The multi-section one should scroll to a certain section according to a current route. Each section has a set of subsections. So the route like 
    #!/section-2/subsection-2
should make the app scroll to Section-2 (smooth scrolling is not an issue at the moment) and activate Subsection 2.

I tried using named ui-views, but then I have to have an initial state of each named ui-view on my route state. It leads to another problem. If let's say I would navigate to 
   #!/section-1/subsection-1
my Section 1 subsection will return to whatever is set in the initial state.
Another issue is that my setup should separate Sections 1-4 from Section 5 which is a separate page.
I hope my description makes sense. Would love to here any advice on what I can read or where can I find some useful ideas. Thanks in advance.

[image: Sections naive sketch]

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##scrollspy ??

Comment: Not really. This one is just an anchor scroll plugin. Doesn't really solve the problem of the routing (specifically with subsections)

Comment: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing as scrollTo built in which might help to give you an idea of an aproach... It is still far from complete though.